# Dynamically hide/show markers when indoor maps floor changed in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-indoor-maps

I am creating one google indoor map application as a part of my project. As of now i just try to create some working prototype before main application gets starts. As of now i am using one college location where i can find indoor maps available.

My main goal is show markers with windowInfo on different floors locations like rooms, theater or auditorium. I just used 1st floor one room lat long and set marker as of now. But when user switch to second floor then map should hide first floor marker and have to show other available markers on floor 2. Same thing would apply for all other floor levels.

Here, my main problem is that how can i get to know exact lat long or location of particular place on floor 2 where i should have to show marker point. Is there any way where google give response of upper floor locations with lat long or some height so i can try to determine that and show marker.

Second confusion is that when user zoom in or out or else user changes floor level at that how we can handle a lot markers hide and show.

Please share your ideas and views on this. As of now i can able to put marker on only first floor. you may find that image below.

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Y Downvote? Without any reason?

Comment: Does, google indoor map detects if user has walked and moved to next floor ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getLevels ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/IndoorBuilding.html)

Gets the levels in the building. While a level is usually enclosed by a single building, a level might be enclosed by several buildings (e.g., a carpark level might span multiple buildings). The levels are in 'display order' from top to bottom.

You can also use various methods in IndoorBuilding class getActiveLevelIndex(), getDefaultLevelIndex(),isUnderground() etc

[Read more about IndoorLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/IndoorLevel.html#activate())

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Using this i can not achieve my goal i guess. Using this i can get floor information not the actual locations which are over there on floor.

Comment: Any comment on my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps include your altitude along with your the lat/long information.  What you need to do is to get your altitude and keep that as a variable.  Then find out what altitude each of the levels of the building are.  I am attempting to do the same thing for a University and that is the only way I knew of where you could know that you are on a second or third floor.  Think of it as having your x,y, and z values.  Lat/Long is basically a 2d representation of the earth's surface. But, you also have a 3rd plane.  You could do the following:  Download a program that not only tells you your lat/long but, also the altitude.  Then have a variable that is a constant for each building.  (building name) (Floor number) (Floor elevation).  Then when you give the building lat/long you also give the elevation variable and then it associates it with a floor number.

Ashe